# Split plot design - help with choosing the analysis

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, split-plot

I have a split-plot design experiment with three levels (slope, then treatment within slope, then cages within each treatment), with the main response being a count of seedlings.

South      South North North  (n4)
↓
Site 1  Site 2 Site 3     (n12)
↓
Treatment 1, Treatment 2, Treatment 3 (with and without cages)

In my initial analysis I assumed no interaction between the levels and ran as a glm of which the results match the graph outputs well.

However, if I was to run the analysis as a proper split plot design which would be the correct analysis to run? I read not an ANOVA due to the count data, and I'm not sure how to add random factor and interactions to the glm. Is a lmer mixed effects model the way to go?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: You wrote that you have an experiment with three "levels."  Did you mean to write three "FACTORS?"  Slope, treatment within the slope, and cages seems like independent variables that affect the outcome of the experiment and would thus be factors in the experimental design terminology.  A level would be "setting" that a factor is set at.  So I'm guessing, for example, you might have set different values of the slope (e.g. 5, 10, 15% grade), and something like presence or no presence of a cage would be the levels of the cage factor.  Perhaps you could clarify and provide more details?

Comment: Yes, three factors. Slope is either north or south facing, treatment is the grass treatment (there are three) and presence and no presence of cage. Like this: